# Xcode randomly deletes files after building

Tags: xcode

I've been experiencing an odd bug with Xcode and it's been happening for a while now. While I am working on a swift iOS project, Xcode randomly deletes a file or two. It's always a random file and I have to go to my GitHub repo copy the code from the specific file and make a new file, name it the same, and copy and paste the code in.

I don't delete the files; all I'm doing as coding in a different portion of my project. Sometimes I build my project 10 times, and it works because the file exists, then suddenly on the next build it fails because the file doesn't exist. I'm on the newest version of Xcode and Swift.

[image: photo]

Comment: You aren't keeping your working copy in iCloud Drive or some other cloud-synced directory, right? Right?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev My working copy is stored inside Finder under the documents section. But I can also view the working copy from Finder -> iCloud Drive -> Documents. I think my copy is stored locally but is also accessible from iCloud Drive, I think that's why it's under 2 sections of my Finder.

Comment: That might be the problem: if you Documents directory is being synced with iCloud, some files can be sporadically deleted only to be redownloaded later from iCloud. Arguably, the best directory to store source code is `~/Developer`.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev where is the Developer folder located on Mac. I do not have that on my system. Do I have to add it?

Comment: Yep, just create it in Finder. It will have a nice Xcode-like hammer icon as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably happening if you keep your source code in iCloud Drive or in an iCloud synced directory (`Documents` or `Desktop`). Many macOS users sync Documents & Desktop` with iCloud. Unfortunately, the system tends to randomly delete local copies of different files in such directories, only keeping the version in the cloud, and apparently Xcode doesn't like it much.

It's better not to use a cloud-synced directory to store source code projects.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Either turn off iCloud syncing for Documents & Desktop in "System Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > iCloud Drive".
2. Or move source code projects to `~/Developer`, that's the recommended location. By default this directory is not there, but if you create it from Finder, it will have a nice Xcode-like hammer icon. To create it, use the Finder's menu command "Go > Home", then create the `Developer` directory in your home directory.